# How can I use complex expressions in Yii2 query

Tags: mysql, yii, yii2

How can I use complex expressions in Yii2 query, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE a & 1 = a
```

By use:

```
Model::find()->where('xxx')->all()
```

What can I use in 'where' expression?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`yii\db\Expression`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-expression):

```
Model::find()
    ->where(new \yii\db\Expression('a & :value = a', [
        ':value' => 1,
    ]))
    ->all()
```